# Field of a parallel plate capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

Pretty much in all the diagrams I have seen the electric field of the parallel plates is depicted as in this image

[image]

The field lines seems to start bending only after leaving the periphery of the plates, shouldn't the field lines be depicted as starting to bend as soon as we start to move away from the exact centre of the capacitor ?

Comment: I think that it is assumed that the length of the plates is very large compared with the separation between them.

Comment: Still it may be negigible but it must start bending

Comment: Well, that's it: if it's negligible, it is only significant near the borders...

Comment: But also near the internal boundaries, which are normally and as far as I have seen the diagrams, always left out, both internal and external boundaries must be shown with same significant bending. It should not be that in internal boundary there are straight lines while curved ones for the outer boundary.

Comment: I can't see your point...

Comment: Leave it I am deleting the post, it is not of much significance most of the time.

Comment: Don't delete questions on a whim unless they're off topic. This isn't too bad a question, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true, however the bending is not much until one comes closer to the edge so it is usually neglected or too small to depict.

Here's what I get when I simulate the system:

[image]

This is the same system as a vector plot:

[image]

Comment: Where and how did you simulate this ?

Comment: @rijulgupta I just plugged in the formulae into _Mathematica_ and used `StreamPlot` and `VectorPlot`

Comment: Thanks ! But what formula did you plot ? I actually tried to derive a formula for the field of capacitor but that got tangled in some serious integrations.

Comment: @rijulgupta $\mathbf E=\left(-\frac{\frac{y-1}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}}-\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{x}-\frac{\frac{y-1}{\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}}-\frac{y}{\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}}}{2-x},\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}}\right)\right)$. It's a pretty easy integration. Usually you can find the formulae in concise form in terms of the angles subtended by the particle on the rod, and then if you really need it in cartesian form it can be easily substituted.

Comment: Yes this is pretty easy, what I was doing was incorporating z axis just as well and thats when it got funny, see I was trying to find field in 3 dimensional space, in fact I have proven this formulae once myself. Thanks a lot.